# Validate Ethereum addresses on JSFiddle or other quick & dirty REPL

Tags: addresses, javascript, python

Can anyone who's gotten the Ethereum utility libraries to work in JSFiddle or Python lend me a headstart?

All I want to do is validate some addresses by hand in a REPL environment (EIP-55 etc).

Tried `pip install ethereum` in my Python 3.6 environment but it fails [with this error](https://pastebin.com/raw/RwDn2BZB).  Not sure why it's trying to invoke binaries from Visual Studio.

Next went to try in a Python 2.7 environment but mine must be buggered as I'm getting:

```
C:\Python27>python -m pip install ethereum
C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named pip
```

even after reinstalling python-2.7.14.amd64.msi to the `C:\Python27` folder and ensuring `pip` is checkmarked (and ensuring my `PYTHONHOME` environment variable is correctly set of course).

Tried to figure out how to import the Ethereum libraries into repl.it (that would be **ideal**) but didn't manage it before moving on.

Was hoping to make a JSFiddle with something like:

`<script src="https://rawgit.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/master/index.js"/>`

but apparently the libraries need to be browserify'ed first.

I could keep kicking at this but I'm sure somebody out there must have already done it.  All I'm looking for is a quick and dirty, friction-free way to get starting playing with the validate functions against some addresses I want to inspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python3.6 install error is because the `scrypt` library is [trying to build with linux headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705751/cannot-open-include-file-unistd-h-no-such-file-or-directory). So, it looks like `scrypt`, and therefore the `ethereum` library, was not designed with Windows support.

The good news is that [`web3.py`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/web3) has [address verification](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#Web3.isChecksumAddress), and should be a straightforward install.

To get started:

```
C:\Python36\Scripts>pip install web3

C:\Python36\Scripts>python
>>> from web3 import Web3
>>> assert Web3.isChecksumAddress('0xFeC2079e80465cc8C687fFF9EE6386ca447aFec4')
```

Since you implied other potential utility needs, you may also be interested in web3's [type conversions](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#type-conversions) and [sha3 hashing](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#cryptographic-hashing).

Answer (score 1):

Just install Metamask, unlock it and in Chrome dev tools console you can access the injected `web3` object:

[image]

Comment: Thanks super helpful!  Sorry I could only pick one "right" answer.